# Object.prototype.method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

i've created this prototype method for Object, but it stops all my code, when i test it, it works for some objects list but followings codes don't work. Thank you to help me.

```js
Object.prototype.toMapIt = function(){
  var arrayFinal = [];
  for(var key in this){
    if(key != "toMapIt"){
      var array = [];
      array.push(key);
      array.push(this[key]);
      arrayFinal.push(array);
    }
  }
  return new Map(arrayFinal);
}
```

```js
//Using the method
var object = {key1 : value1, key2 : value2};

var map = object.toMapIt();
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: What's not working about it? This isn't a minimal example for us to go by.

Comment: So what you're actually after is a way to list all the keys and values in an object? For what purpose? To print them out?

Comment: hi , there's no error in the console.

Comment: I want to convert Object into Map.

Comment: What are value1 and value2?

Comment: Try `object.toMapIt()` instead of `object.toMap()`!

Comment: thanks Bergi, sorry for the error here, but it was object.toMapIt() in my code.

Answer (score 0):

So i don't have problem with this :

```js
var toMap = function(object){
  var finalArray = [];
  for(var key in object){
      var array = [];
      array.push(key);
      array.push(object[key]);
      finalArray.push(array);
  }
  return new Map(finalArray);
}


$(function(){
  
  var test = {ko : "jiioji", opop : "ijoijoij"};

  console.log(test);
  console.log(toMap(test));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>See your console</p>
<p>I've made this function because i have big objects, and i want to use some map properties on this objects</p>
```